# Embedded logging

Tags: c++, c, logging, embedded

Logging is an essential debug facility. How do you use such logging functions in embedded environments? I personally program on ARM Cortex Mx microcontrollers.

I was thinking of a logging framework with a changeable backend for several Interfaces (ITM, UART,...) and customizable levels of logging.

I found [A Highly Configurable Logging Framework In C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/225700666). Do you know any other projects?

Comment: I know this question is around for quite some time, so my answer may not be helpful to the original author. But just in case somebody stumbles across it, just like I did: There is an embedded software / firmware library ([www.redblocks.de](http://www.redblocks.de/en/redblocks-component-library/blocks/logging-framework/)) I am currently evaluating which offers a pretty flexible and lightweight logging framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In embedded systems, logging is accomplished in two preferred methods:  via debug / serial port and storing into memory.

The idea behind storing into memory is that it can be retrieved later using a JTAG debugger or other facilities.  Use Non-Volatile memory for anything that needs to be saved after power-off.

Comment: Well, I actually wrote my own logging system. Backend can be a debugger, serial interface, stdout or other medium which implements an abstract base class.

Comment: Good idea. A a framework for file IO as well, virtual console, that Segger think that's a shell around the IRM (forgot it's name).